# nodejs utilising a route within a route to access data example

Tags: node.js, routes, chartist.js

I have a route which generates 5 random numbers and forms it to an array. I want to use this array to populate a chart using chartist.

I can presently used fixed data and graph it, now I want to link up the two.

```java
function show_graph() {
            myChart.update({
            labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            series: [
                [1, 2, 5, 2, 1]
            ]
        });
    }
```

I then have this server route which generates the 5 values

```java
router.get("/random", function(req,res)
{
    var arr = [];
    while(arr.length < 5){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
    }
    console.log(arr);
    res.status(200).send({results: arr});
});
```

My question is how do I use them together. So I can use this results variable to populate my series.
Do I need to use re direct or how do I call the route as I just want the result.

Note I am using nodejs with express and my charting api is chartist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your front-end? Is it a `single-page-application` or `web pages`?

Comment: @Daniel My front end is an ejs page(extended javascript) which goes to a web application via browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. Firstly was to import jQuery and use a route call to my function within the random route.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

```java
var getData = $.get("/random");
        //alert(getData);
        getData.done(function(res)
        {
            console.log(res.results);
            myChart.update({
            labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            series: [
                res.results
            ]
            
            });
        });
```